# Create a Laravel / PHP script that runs periodically e.g. every 1 week to update my MySQL database with calls to an api

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

The reason for my question is because I've tried to implement this by just calling the api from my code within my website, but because there so many calls the initial page times out after 30 seconds, and you don't really want your users waiting longer than 2 / 3 seconds for a page on a website to load.

So I was wondering how I would write a Laravel / PHP function that would pull all the information from the API calls into my MSQL database and query the database instead.  I was also wondering how I would get this to run periodically as mentioned in the subject.

Please let me know your thoughts, and what you reckon would be the best approach going forward in accomplishing this task which I was hoping would have been a lot more trivial than what it's turned out to be.

Comment: There should be [plenty of examples around the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=laravel+cron).

Comment: @halfer I actually did a bit of searching before I posted here, hence my question on so.

Comment: Currently I am working On Laravel APIs and Scheduling. Using Scheduling I can execute my code on basis of every minute to yearly. So what you are trying to do? can you explain more, SO I can guide you better

Comment: @Qazi thanks for your reply, I'm looking at creating a Laravel Schedule that will call the following APIs [link]http://nitro.noxgroup.co.za/v2/inventory?apiKey=ApiKey, and [link]http://nitro.noxgroup.co.za/v2/inventory/PropertyID?apiKey=ApiKey and load them into a MySQL database, as before I was trying to call it from within my website via a Helper class called CurlHelper which basically calls curl_exec($curl) setting the necessary curl options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduling will not call your API directly. the way is, when you create a scheduling command, then there you should Write your code which will trigger the API(using curl, file_get_contents or any suitable method), it will give you response and you can manipulate it according to your requirement.

Once done, you have to simply execute the command in terminal or through cron settings, that command will trigger your code(API call which you wrote in command handle method)

Follow below documentation, let me know if you have any difficulties in implementation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling

This is video tutorial, creation of scheduling command and accessing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp-XZm7INl8

Comment: Great thanks very much for the reply Qazi, I think I'm going to mark this as the correct answer as it definitely seems like the right way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Sure, if you think so, if you feel any issue, you can ask here.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it Qazi.